# How do you run an application in bash and select which monitor it runs on?

Tags: linux, qt

I have a question that is hard to search for the answer (I always end up with answers for monitor manipulation). I am writing a bash shell script to help me with my code dev and I have two monitors.

When I run my executable that I have compiled I want to tell it to run on a particular monitor (i.e. different to the monitor that I have my terminal open on so I can view the debug on one screen and have the app on another).

How would I go about doing this? Something like:

```
./myProject > but run on monitor 2
```

Where `myProject` is my binary executable.

Thanks all.

Comment: Please specify whether this is a graphical application, a simple console aplication, and whether this uses any toolkit like ncurses.

Comment: This is going to depend on your window manager, and how it selects where to display a new window.

Comment: When you say run my executable on another monitor. Do I understand correctly, your app is GUI based application? bash has nothing to do with positioning in that case. The library you are using to create the window may have some methods to lock the window position.

Comment: It is a GUI (Qt) app. When I run the app in bash it always starts the app on the same monitor. If I move the terminal to a different monitor then the app starts on that monitor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you run separate displays on each monitor (less likely these days), the `DISPLAY` environment variable is what you want.

If you use Xinerama (spreading one logical display across multiple monitors), however:

- Aside: X11 vocabulary: A "display" is one or more "screens" with input devices; e.g. keyboard and mouse, a.k.a. a "seat." A "screen" is a logical canvas that is partially or completely displayed on one or more "monitors;" when using multiple monitors for one "screen," the windows can be partially displayed on each monitor, but share the same X11 `DISPLAY` identifier; this is called Xinerama. The `DISPLAY` format is *host* `:` *display-number* `.` *screen-id*, so e.g. on my Xinerama set-up both monitors are part of screen `0` on a display number that counts up from `0` with each logged-in user on the same host. "Seats" are logical groups of monitor+input that are using different hardware; multiple "displays" can occur using "virtual console" switching, which is how Gnome and KDE allow multiple users to sign in on a single "seat" machine.

Most GUI toolkits allow you to specify the window's geometry using the `--geometry` or `-geometry` switch.

- Qt uses the older MIT-style `-geometry` form. GTK+/Gnome uses the GNU-style `--geometry`.
- This assumes that you're allowing Qt to post-process your command-line, e.g. passing `argv` into `QtApplication` or similar.

The “logical display” will have a resolution which is the sum of the resolutions in each direction of the arrangement of your monitors. For example, I have 2 × 1920×1080 displays hooked up right now. `xrandr` reports:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
```

To display a window on the right-hand monitor, I can give a geometry string that has its `x` co-ordinates between 1920…3839 (inclusive).

The usual format is: *width* `x` *height* `±` *x-offset* `±` *y-offset* ­­— but the width and height are optional, if you prefer to take the defaults. The `±` are `+` to count relative to the top/left, or `-` to count relative to the bottom/right.

So, for example:

```
gedit --geometry 800x600+1920+0  # set size at top-left of right screen
gedit --geometry +1920+100       # default size at top-left of right screen
gedit --geometry -0+0            # default size at top-right of entire display
```

Unfortunately, the only programmatic way I know of to determine the area of the display on each monitor from the shell would be to parse the output from `xrandr`; e.g.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768       60.0 +
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   640x480        60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   640x480        60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

$ xrandr | perl -ne 'if (/(\d+)x(\d+)\+(\d+)\+(\d+)/) '\
> ' { print "$3,$4 - ", $3 + $1 - 1, ",", $4 + $2 - 1, "\n" }'
0,0 - 1919,1079
1920,0 - 3839,1079
```

(You'd normally want to avoid splitting the Perl one-liner across two lines in the shell, but the `'\`…`'` trick there is to make it legible on SO.)

Comment: As I mentioned to John, I don't seem to have display :0.1 (even though I have two monitors). I think this is because my desktop is spread accross both monitors (if I understood your explanation) this means that I have only one display.

Comment: Using gedit I could use the --display=DISPLAY, but I could not use the --geometry option... its just not there!, but I think you are right because I seem to recall using it once in the past and I can see google examples of it. I have ubuntu 10.04, so this is quite old (the guys at work are not very willing to move on : (( ). But ultimatley my Qt application does not support any options of this sort, so I suppose I would have to implement them? - Is there not a bash command that tells the launcher (err... the kernel?) where to put the window?

Comment: Finally... thanks for your detailed explanations... if I can move to Ubuntu 12 or even 13 I think these options may work :)

Comment: Wait.... I got it a bit wrong! I thought that geometry was not available, but it is in some cases. If I type in (for example) "gedit --help" I get some help, but not all. I have to do gedit --help-all and then I see a full list of options. Turns out I can't do geometry with gedit, but I CAN do it gnome-terminal which means I can run my app in the same window as my terminal (I can't change that) but I can then open a new gnome-terminal whereever I like using the geometry and then use that to display my debug using tail -f (or such)! - done! ... well, I have to do it... but its trivial. Thanks!

Comment: Strange that your GEdit is missing that; it's provided by the common code in GTK+/GDK (as well as Qt) … note also you can pass a `-e` to `gnome-terminal` to start a certain program, or even create a Profile specifically to run it with certain settings (e.g. run `tail` with different colours than your default shell)

Comment: +1 - Using -e worked nicely!, now I have that all running with a single command! (does a local build, then runs the app, then opens a term with tail running :)  ... looks cool when the ol' boss walks by and I hit "run" and all that is going off in the background while I chat to them :)

Answer (score 7):

The `--geometry` answer given above and accepted simply won't work in many cases...

There are a lot of near-identical questions like this floating around the various StackExchange sites & AskUbuntu, the answer I've eventually found (on a Linux Mint distro based on Ubuntu 14.04) is to use `wmctrl`. I'm leaving an answer just since no one else has mentioned it on this thread.

(There's another called `Devil's Pie` and another called `Compiz` if you search for those too you'll find the Q&A's I'm talking about)

`wmctrl` is the sort of simple unix tool you're probably looking for if you're writing Bash scripts. I also saw someone suggest using `xdotool`, depends what the specific goal is.

`wmctrl` offers window matching by window title or `pid` (not compatible with all types of X-managed windows)

Some helpful resources:

- [`wmctrl` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl)
- [user doc 1](https://sites.google.com/site/tstyblo/wmctrl/)
- [user doc 2](http://blog.spiralofhope.com/1042/wmctrl-user-documentation.html)
- “[How to shift applications from workspace 1 to 2 using command?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31240/how-to-shift-applications-from-workspace-1-to-2-using-command)”
- [More specific answer RE: specifying the dimensions](https://superuser.com/questions/297819/move-window-to-another-monitor-in-ubuntu-using-keyboard)
- “[Both `wmctrl` and `xdotool` work fine if you set a window *maximized*.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739155/why-cant-i-move-a-window-to-the-top-left-corner-with-wmctrl-in-unity?atw=1)”

I connect a second monitor on the left or on the right depending on where I'm working each day, and I think the solution for me will involve

- finding the dimensions from `xrandr` (as shown in *BRPocock*'s answer),
- parsing that to tell which is the external connected monitor (VGA/HDMI etc.) rather than the inbuilt one,
- specifying a dimension to give to a maximised window on the connected screen (i.e. the left/right/top/bottom offset, which will change according to side of the screen being used)

Leaving my notes and [eventually] some code produced [here](https://github.com/lmmx/devnotes/wiki/wmctrl-dual-monitor-specification) in case it's useful to anyone else.

Comment: Sorry - very late on this one, but some activity occured on this post and so I just noticed your answer now and read it. Pretty cool, just took a look at wmctrl. I do still use --geometry, most of the main terminals support it and its easy to use, but +1 for a nice looking solution I will give it a go : )

Answer (score 4):

Use a `fifo`

open a terminal window on the monitor you want the output to appear on and do

```
mkfifo /tmp/myfifo
cat /tmp/myfifo
```

then on the source terminal do

```
./myProject >/tmp/myfifo
```

This assumes it is a console app. If it is graphical then you will need another approach, which will be dependent on what windowing manager + toolkit you are using.

Comment: hmm... very cool, but not quite what I want, my app is a GUI... infact lets just say its gedit or xemacs or somthing and I want to open it on the other monitor. I am using Ubuntu (if that helps?)

Comment: Not used ubuntu in a while. You used to be able to control things by setting `DISPLAY`, e.g. `export DISPLAY=:0.1;./myProject` (need to play with the numbers), but that may well not work with multi-monitor these days.

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is set the `DISPLAY` environmental variable prior to running your application.

To find out what you need to set it to, run the following on the monitor you want it to show up on:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

You should see, for example `:0.1` or `:0.0`.

Then you can specify that you want your app to run on that display like so:

```
DISPLAY=:0.1 ./my_app
```

Comment: Thanks for that one... I think it would have worked, but when I tried it I don't seem to have a :0.1 display. I have two monitors with my desktop spread across both so they are not seperate screens. Maybe if I use "twin desktop" instead of "spread" then this would work :(

Answer (score 0):

As your application uses QT, you are probably using KDE. In `System Settings > Window Behavior > Advanced`, set `Placement` to `Under Mouse`. Click the desired monitor, ALT+Tab to switch to your terminal, and start the program.

Comment: I dont have KDE, but I did look for a similar option... with no success :(  ...I have Ubuntu with gnome